# Which Site to Ask About Computing Definitions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following two questions:

1. Is there such a thing as an "Encoding Language"?
2. If so, what is an "Encoding Language"?

But, I am unsure on which site to do so. This is because of 2 reasons:

1. I saw [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5729/do-computer-terminology-questions-belong-here-or-on-elu?lq=1) on Meta Super User but it didn't really answer my question. The answers and comments were somewhat confusing to me, and didn't seem to provide any definitive conclusion.
2. Although I'm sure Question #2 fits Super User as a similarly based question was linked to at the SU/EL&U post above, I think Question #1 would better fit EL&U. However, I'm not going to split the two questions on two different groups because they're contextually bound (since Q2 can only be answered if Q1 is answered and answered as TRUE.

Comment: might be helpful in this context to explain what you think the definition of "Encoding Language" is, especially what "Language" is in the context of your question - is it a **programming** language, a spoken language, or another use?

Comment: What does Google/Bing/etc. tell you an "Encoding Language" is (especially if you search for the phrase not just the words)? Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I didn't include that because I figured it's irrelevant. I'm not asking the question, merely where I should ask the question. I didn't to waste your time.

Comment: Also, psubsee2003, I'm using this in the context of computing. Take Unicode, for example: we know it's not a programming language, as it doesn't "programme" anything, i.e. it doesn't tell the computer to really *do* something, like Python, Ruby, C++ and so forth do. We also know it's not a markup language because it isn't an annotative (as opposed to a programming) language like HTML.

Comment: Every source I've read and every person I've spoken/communicated with has told me that Unicode is an "encoding standard". But it could also **very** easily qualify as a language due to the fact that it has its own grammar, syntax, its own components, and even its own meta-standards. (Although it'd be a very *basic* language since its function is, effectively, merely to translate information from a human-oriented language to a computer-oriented language.) 

However, I didn't want to say I "coined" this term somehow if it turns out it already exists. xD

Comment: Anyway, for the record, I looked on Google's [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) and couldn't find any information on it. I've done extensive Google searching and I couldn't really find any sources that said what it was, though. Most sources were either just using using the term in a standard code expression or used it in regular ol' English sentences but without any accompanying explanation of its definition.

Comment: The closest I could find was [this page](https://help.comodo.com/topic-169-1-413-4468-.html) from the Comodo Ice Dragon help pages, which mentions "Character Encoding Languages", although I'm unsure if that's the same thing; and even if it is, I still don't even know what *those* are. xD